# how to check if a user and group exist before creating them on windows (NOT AD user or group)

Tags: powershell

i would like to check if a user or group exist before creating them on the windows system not (Active Directory)

for instance this is how i create the group:

```
$ADSI = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:ComputerName"
$FTPUserGroup = $ADSI.Create("Group", "$FTPUserGroupName")
$FTPUserGroup.SetInfo()
$FTPUserGroup.Description = "Members of this group can connect through FTP"
$FTPUserGroup.SetInfo()
```

Comment: Take a look at [Get-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) and [Get-LocalGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroup?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: as boxdog pointed out, the newer versions of PoSh have built in cmdlets for doing that. what version of PoSh will you be using this code with?

Comment: i will be implementing this on windows 2008 to windows 2019